# The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity WCF Service

Tags: wcf, web-config

I am currently trying to access a hosted WCF service using a locally hosted website, which is running successfully on the server (I am able to access the wsdl etc).

I am getting the error:

```
The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IBetFriendService/SelectCustomerUsernamePasswordLogin' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.
```

I have increased both receiveTimeout and inactivityTimeout to 12:00:00 but i am still getting the error.

Web Config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IBetFriendService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="12:00:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="12:30:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://bet-friend.org.uk/BetFriendLibrary.BetFriendService.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IBetFriendService1"
        contract="BetFriendServiceReference2.IBetFriendService" name="WSHttpBinding_IBetFriendService1">
        <identity>
          <dns />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

WCF Config Snippet:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="BetFriendLibrary.BetFriendService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="BetFriendLibrary.IBetFriendService">
      <identity>
        <dns />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://bet-friend.org.uk/BetFriendLibrary.BetFriendService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
     </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I have enabled tracing on this and now have the following error: The remote endpoint has sent an unrecognized fault with namespace, http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope, name Sender, and reason The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/CreateSequence' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity.

Comment: Have you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also got same issues, once delete my all reference and then i will create the once again. the code working fine.. try you also... best of luck...

Thanks,

Ramesh Periyasamy